# How can we have he similar decomposition of $ \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

We have,

$\mathbb{Q}_p=$p-adic field, $\mathbb{Z}_p=$ring of p-adic integers, $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}=$multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

We have the following decompositions:

$\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}=\mu_{p-1} \times (1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$,

where $\mu_{p-1}$ is the group of roots of unity of order $ \ p-1$,

$\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}=p^{\mathbb{Z}} \times \mu_{p-1} \times (1+p\mathbb{Z}_p) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /(p-1) \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

**The question is**-

How can we have he similar decomposition of   $ \ \mathbb{Q}_p[\zeta_p]^{\times}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ ?

Comment: It is obvious how to go from $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]^\times$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)^\times$. I don't see what you mean with a decomposition of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. And my previous comment was incorrect. $\zeta_p-1$ is an uniformizer. Is there some $\pi = a (\zeta_p-1), a \in \mathbb{Z}_p[\pi]^\times$ such that $(1+\pi)^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $1+\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\pi]$ ? If it doesn't depend on $a$ then no since $a = 1$ gives $(1+\pi)^{\mathbb{Z}} = \zeta_p^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @reuns,  what is decomposition of $ \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]^{\times}$  and $ \mathbb{Q}_p[\zeta_p]^{\times}$

Comment: I think the best way to start is then with the $p$-adic $\log,\exp$, showing for some $k$ that  $\log,\exp$ is a pair of isomomorphism $1+\pi^k \mathbb{Z}_p[\pi] \leftrightarrow \pi^k \mathbb{Z}_p[\pi]$. Then use $\mathbb{Z}_p[\pi]^\times/(1+\pi^k \mathbb{Z}_p[\pi] )$ is finite. This is also a proof $(1+\pi)^\mathbb{Z}$ is never dense in $1+\pi\mathbb{Z}_p[\pi] $